# cannot load modules from redisgears in docker

Tags: docker, redis

when following along the tutorial https://developer.redis.com/develop/java/redis-and-spring-course/lesson_1/,
I cloned the repo:
`git clone --branch course/milestone-1 git@github.com:redis-developer/redi2read.git --recurse-submodule`
and tried to run :  `docker-compose up`.
then I encounter the error:

```
# Module /var/opt/redislabs/lib/modules/redisgears.so failed to load: /var/opt/redislabs/lib/modules/redisgears.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
docker-redis-1  | 1:M 10 Oct 2023 17:55:30.371 # Can't load module from /var/opt/redislabs/lib/modules/redisgears.so: server aborting
```

I download the image from ***redislabs/redismod:latest***, so it should contain redisgears.
I noticed the script in docker-compose is different for redisgears:

```
        --loadmodule /usr/lib/redis/modules/redisbloom.so
        --loadmodule /var/opt/redislabs/lib/modules/redisgears.so
```

should I modify that to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Changing that redisgears.so route to:

```
/usr/lib/redis/modules/redisgears.so
```

fixes the problem for me.